# Managing keychain from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, security, keychain

I want to move my keys from `login` keychain to `system` keychain from terminal. Is that possible? I checked the [security](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html) manual but I can not see the option there to do so.

Comment: You commented this is for Xcode on a server. There are better approaches to giving Xcode access to keys and certificates that do not involve `system.keychain`. Please can you ask a question that deals with what you really want to solve.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355637/using-a-non-default-keychain-in-xcode/6645998#6645998 for an example of getting Xcode to use a non-default keychain. You can unlock and leave a keychain accessible without a password, if needed.

Comment: It would be interesting if there is a python / api bridge to access all the internal code?  there are some details at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items after looking into the /Library/Keychains file you might lookup how to access "binary" keychain "sqlite" data via python? that seems a bit dangerous to try and do.. whats the situation your trying to solve? backups?

Answer (score 3):

**Why?**

The login keychain is for your user account. Moving that data to the system keychain would make your information available to all user accounts including 'Guest' accounts. Do you really want to do that?

I don't know if it is possible to do what you want, but if I look at my login keychain it includes my personal passwords, Apple ID, public keys (no problem), and **private** keys. These should ***never*** be made available to anyone. They are **private** for a reason.

Don't do this.

Comment: Yes i know whats that mean and i want to do this. Its needed for Xcode server to operate on system Keychain

Comment: Good luck then. I see dump-keychain, export & import. That should get you somewhere